# Creating JWT with JWK signature

Tags: c#, jwt, token, rsa, jwk

I'm learning about tokens using .Net Framework. One thing I cannot seem to find is how to create a token with a signature made with JWK. I found plethora of articles explaining how to validate JWT with JWKS, and how to sign JWT with RSA or HMAC.

I tried using libraries like BouncyCastle and jose-jwt, but the format of JWK is encoded differently, and would not be accepted. I successfully created and signed tokens using ssh-keygen RSA keys, but I can't get the CRT variables for decoding from these.

I wish to just take JWK-generated keys and use them, just like I would use the ssh-keygen ones